How did she "knew"?
I found this line in a book:

Wednesday afternoon at two-thirty she legs it to London and buys a
radio scanner for two and a half thousand quid. Any good theories why?
And how the hell did she knew how to use it?’

I was pretty sure that "knew" is a typo here and that it should be "know" instead. But books don't tend to have many errors, so I asked ChatGPT for its opinion.
This was its response:

The use of "knew" instead of "know" in this sentence isn't a typo;
it's grammatically correct. Here's why:
The sentence seems to be a narrative recounting something that
happened in the past. Since the speaker is reflecting on a past event
("Wednesday afternoon at two-thirty she legs it to London..."), the
verb tense continues to be past throughout.
Thus, the past tense "knew" is used because the speaker is asking how
she had the knowledge in the past (at the time she bought the scanner)
and is maintaining consistency with the narrative's past tense.
This would be the same in both British and American English.

It hasn't really convinced me. Is ChatGPT on the mark or not?

I would remove the information from ChatGPT, which is known to be an unreliable source and isn't relevant to the question. Also: can you provide the surrounding context in the book, including the book's title and the page number?

I’m voting to close this question because it based on the misapprehension that ChatGPT can speak English.

"Books don't tend to have many errors" HA ha ha ha!!! There are very, very, very few books without errors. Since this is dialogue, or at least narrative in a "voice," it's also possible that the error is supposed to be the speaker's, perhaps intentional and whimsical. But I feel like for this question to have traction, we need a better foundation for why it should not be dismissed as a typo.

It could be a representation of colloquial speech, perhaps within a dialect. There can be ungrammatical patterns in colloquial speech. You can come across them in written form in novels usually.

ChatGPT is spouting complete nonsense. It's a typo

https://www.google.it/books/edition/Dead_Simple/qoBuPWxCcK8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Wednesday+afternoon+at+two-thirty+she+legs+it+to+London%22&pg=PA414&printsec=frontcover Written by Peter James. Not a typo all the editions report the same sequence.

Your qustion stands a better chance of being reopened  if in an edit 1. You include the author's name (Peter James) 3. Show that it is not a one-off typo; it has been reprinted several times 2. Just ask why the verb is not in the bare infinitive and maybe we'll find out it's dialectal 3. Delete all references to ChatGPT, people begin to react emotively and irrationally when that term appears.

However... ChatGPT doesn't know grammar, and will misread and misinterpret requests. Much depends on the prompt you supplied.

The better way to ask this very question might be "Should I ever use this bizarre form of the verb?" Sorta doesn't matter if it's a typo in this book. And the answer is no, don't gone there, it's an unknewn form, reviled whenever encountered.

The paragraph in the OP contains informal speech, as indicated by words/phrases like quid and leg it, which suggest British English slang. In some northern British dialects, particularly in Yorkshire and Lancashire, you may also encounter non-standard verb forms in tense usage.

Do not ever ask ChatGPT for advice or see what it thinks. It doesn't think and isn't meant to provide advice (it's creators specifically point this out). It is mean to produce human-like text patterns. That's all it does.
